# ERROR: CHECK_NRPE: Socket timeout after 10 seconds

Tags: iptables, amazon-ec2, nagios, aws, nrpe

getting following error :

```
# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H nagios-server-ip
CHECK_NRPE: Socket timeout after 10 seconds.
```

But it's working for localhost

```
# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H localhost
NRPE v2.15
```

ps i have checked security groups as well as iptables

Also on Nagios server :

```
# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H localhost
NRPE v2.13
[root@ADM-PROD-NAGIOS ec2-user]# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H monitoring-host-ip
NRPE v2.15
```

Comment: do you have nagios client running in the remote machine? Do you have opened 5666/tcp alllow Nagios IP in the AWS console firewall?

Comment: I guess # /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H localhost
NRPE v2.15 this on remote hosts proves nagios client is running on remote machine

Comment: # netstat -at | grep nrpe
tcp        0      0 *:nrpe                  *:*                     LISTEN

Answer (score 1):

There are two thing in `nrpe.cfg`.

1. `allowed_hosts`
2. `server_address`

In `allowed_host` we should mention public IP of Nagios server if it is outside the LAN.

In `server_address` we should mention the IP of the local machine which is to listen nrpe, because we might have multiple ethernet ports enabled and IPs associated with it.